# How do I style an input[range]'s thumb using ONLY javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have a range/slider `<input type="range">`And I got some css to make it look like this:
 [image: Image of a slider with a color range]
I would like the *thumb* to change color as it slides, I got the JS down that I can get the color based on it's value 1-100 but I don't know how to access the range's thumb. Everywhere I look I can access the thumb via CSS but nothing on JS.

My attempts been similar to:

```
slider.thumb //undefined
slider.shadowRoot //null
slider.style.webkitSliderThumb // undefined
slider.style.thumb // undefined
slider.childNodes  // []
slider.children // []
```

Comment: show us complete example - need to see your code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way is to use `CSS Variables` to then pass on the color to the psuedoselector. I have put a very simple example together below:

```js
const input = document.querySelector( 'input' );

input.addEventListener( 'input', event => {
   
   // This assigns the strength of the color to a CSS variable, which will in turn style the slider.
   input.style.setProperty( '--color', `rgba(${input.value},0,0,1)`);
  
})
```

```css
:root {
  --color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
}
input[type=range] {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1em;
  appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background: linear-gradient( 90deg, black, red );
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  background: var(--color, white);
  appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" value="1" min="0" max="255" step="1" />
```

The elegant bit here is that its nice compatible with all old browsers as well, as you can define the default of white for those people who couldnt be bothered to get modern browsers.

And no, there is no access for pseudo elements in JS as they are... not *technically* there.

Comment: @FrustratedProgrammer yup, its pretty new but very useful!